# Start application automatically on receiving some notification in Android

Tags: android, android-notifications

I have developed an application and installed it on my device.Now what I want to do is to start that application automatically when I receive notification triggered by pending intent previously set by Alarm Manager.Is there any way to start app automatically on some event? Kindly provide suggestions.

Thank you

Comment: @Shayanpourvatan : Can you plz explain in detail?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using IntentService  inside

```
  protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent){}
```

method  you can add your activity which you want to open on notification click like

```
  Intent notifIntent = new Intent(this, CalledScreen.class);
    notifIntent.putExtra(CalledScreen.SCREEN_KEY, CalledScreen.SCREEN_NOTIF);
    notifIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
   PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notifIntent, 0);
```

Hope it will work , if any help require add coment.

Comment: Thanks for rplying but I want to open Automatically not on notification click.My app should open as soon as I receive notification of that app.

Answer (score 0):

Activity class for intent must be declared in AndroidManifest.xml.

```
     PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, Class.forName("XXX.Main")), 0);
             builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
```

Where XXX is your project id, for example: com.mycompany.mygame